# Extracting CustomXMLPart Data from ContentControl

Tags: xml, vba, ms-word

I have an XML document which is just a word document saved as one big XML file

I can see in the XML that the topics which are ContentControls from the Word Document have tags

```
<pkg:part pkg:name="/customXml/item9.xml" ....>
<pkg:xmlData>
<er:document ....>
...
<er:heading sdt-id="398909766" title="SUBPART A – GENERAL"/>
<er:toc>
<er:topic sdt-id="-367401465" source-title="CS 25.1 Applicability"
 ERulesId="ERULES-1963177438-9651"   Domain="Initial airworthiness;"
 ActivityType="" AircraftUse="" AircraftCategory="" AmendedBy="Amendment 11;" 
 ApplicabilityDate="4 July, 2011" EntryIntoForceDate="4 July, 2011"
 EquivalentForeignRegulation="" ICAOReference="" Keywords=""
 RegistryState="" RegulatedEntity="" RegulatorySource="ED Decision 2011/004/R"
 RegulatorySubject="CS-25;" TechnicalSubjectMatter="" TypeOfContent="CS (Certification specification);" 
ParentIR="" EASACategory=""/>
</er:toc>
```

Which match the XML Mapping Pane Custom XML Part as can be seen in this screenshot of Word
[Screenshot of Word showing Custom XML Part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sMiB.png)

I have currently got the following VBA code that pulls out the ContentControl text but I can't workout how to get the Custom XML Part tags,  all the stuff I've found is about adding Custom XML Parts or deleting them but not about retrieving them.

Any help would be most appreciated.

```
Sub ExtractTopic()
'
' ExtractTopic Macro
'
'
    Dim ctrl As ContentControl
    Dim xml As CustomXMLPart
    
    Dim Path As String
    Dim FileNumber As Integer
    Dim FirstHeading As Boolean
    
    Path = ActiveDocument.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "TestOutput.xml"
    FileNumber = FreeFile
    
    Open Path For Output As #FileNumber
    
    FirstHeading = True
    Print #FileNumber, "<ctrls>"
    
    For Each xml In ActiveDocument.CustomXMLParts
        If InStr(xml.NamespaceURI, "easa") Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next xml
    
    For Each ctrl In ActiveDocument.ContentControls
        Select Case ctrl.Title
            Case "heading"
                If Not FirstHeading Then
                   Print #FileNumber, "<\heading>"
                End If
                Print #FileNumber, "<heading>"
                Print #FileNumber, ctrl.Range.Text
            Case "topic"
                Print #FileNumber, "<topic>"
                Print #FileNumber, "<id=" & ctrl.ID & "\>"
                Print #FileNumber, "<text>"
                Print #FileNumber, ctrl.Range.Text
                Print #FileNumber, "<\text>"
                Print #FileNumber, "<\topic>"
            Case Else
                Print #FileNumber, "<" & ctrl.Title & ">"
                Print #FileNumber, "<\" & ctrl.Title & ">"
        End Select
        
    Next ctrl
    
    Print #FileNumber, "<\heading>"
    Print #FileNumber, "<\ctrls>"
    
    Close FileNumber
End Sub
```

Comment: Look into `ctrl.XMLMapping`

Comment: See the responses of Greg Maxey and Jay Freedman in this question: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-can-i-find-the-content-of-a-content-control/13daa6a1-3b1f-4d4b-8ef1-7a22889ba1a7?LastReply=true#LastReply